# Error: Expected a type, but 'SOMETHING has kind ‘SomeMyKind’

Tags: haskell

In this code (snippet) I get an error:

```
• Expected a type, but ‘'ResourcesM’ has kind ‘Msg’
• In the type ‘'ResourcesM’
  In the expression:
    toCache
      @'ResourcesM undefined undefined (AnyMsgPkt GetResourcesMP)
      undefined
  In an equation for ‘fff’:
      fff
        = toCache
......................
```

the code:

```hs
data MsgPkt (m::Msg) (d::MsgDir) where
  GetResourcesMP :: MsgPkt 'ResourcesM 'AskMD
  MyResourcesMP :: MyResources -> MsgPkt 'ResourcesM 'AnsMD
  ......

data AnyMsgPkt (d::MsgDir) = forall (m::Msg). AnyMsgPkt (MsgPkt m d)

.........

class ConcrMsg (m::Msg) (d::MsgDir) where concrMsg :: AnyMsgPkt d -> Maybe (MsgPkt m d)
instance ConcrMsg 'ResourcesM d where
  concrMsg (AnyMsgPkt a@GetResourcesMP{}) = Just a
  concrMsg (AnyMsgPkt a@MyResourcesMP{})  = Just a
  concrMsg _                              = Nothing

..........

class Cached (m::Msg) a where
  fromCache :: Maybe UTCTime -> IPv4 -> a -> Cache -> Hit (AnsTo a)
  toCache :: UTCTime -> IPv4 -> a -> AnsTo a -> Cache -> Cache


instance forall (m::Msg).
    (ConcrMsg m 'AnsMD, Cacheable (MsgPkt m 'AskMD) ~ 'Yes)
    => Cached (AnyMsgPkt 'AskMD) where
  fromCache mbExpir ip v cst = do
    Val valExpir dat <- M.lookup (Key ip 0 $ hash v) cst
    expir <- mbExpir
    False <- pure (valExpir < expir)
    _ <- concrMsg @m dat
    pure dat
  toCache expir ip v ans cst = M.insert (Key ip 0 $ hash v) (Val expir ans) cst

fff = toCache @'ResourcesM undefined undefined (AnyMsgPkt GetResourcesMP) undefined
```

I tried `toCache @ResourcesM ....` (which is wrong from my point of view). but the error is same. How to fix it?

**EDIT 1**

Adding to a parameter `(m::Msg)` to the class `Cached` fixed the problem.

Comment: The preferred way to indicate you've solved your own problem is to post an answer, rather than editing the question. Don't worry that posting an answer to your own question is weird -- in the SO culture that is considered to be a great outcome of having a question.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to write `toCache @'ResourcesM ...` the type class of the `toCache` must have a type parameter of a kind `Msg`, if to add it:

```hs
class Cached (m::Msg) a where   -- HERE, the m
  fromCache :: Maybe UTCTime -> IPv4 -> a -> Cache -> Hit (AnsTo a)
  toCache :: UTCTime -> IPv4 -> a -> AnsTo a -> Cache -> Cache
```

everything becomes OK, now type "argument" `m` is "declared" in the scope of the class and can be passed with type application `@'SOMETHING`